Time Complexity of T(n) = 7T(n/2) + n^2 and T(n) = 7T(n/3) + n^2
What is the Time Complexity of T(n) = 7T(n/3) + n^2  and T(n) = 7T(n/2) + n^2 >>>>I applied both akra-bazzi and master theorem but I get different answer....
for T(n) = 7T(n/3) + n^2 using akra-bazzi theorem i get O(n^2) and using the same theorem on
T(n) = 7T(n/2) + n^2 I get O(n^2) again, but in other network resources they say it would give O(n^log7) using master's theorem. So I am confused between the actual answer.

According to the master theorem,
The solution to the recurrence relation,

T(n) = aT(n/b) + cn^k, where a ≥ 1, b ≥ 2 are integers,
and c and k are positive constants, satisfies

T(n) is

Θ(n^(log_b(a))) if a > b^k
Θ(n^k log(n))   if a = b^k
Θ(n^k)          if a < b^k

Since T(n) = 7T(n/2) + n^2 then a = 7 ≥ 1 and b = 2 ≥ 2. Also, for k = 2 we have 7 > 2^2 = 4 therefore T(n) is Θ(n^(log_2(7))). By the definition of big theta then we know T(n) is also O(n^(log_2(7))) = O(n^2.81) = O(n^3).
I am not sure how you get quadratic time?

Thanks Bud....Actually i had made one silly mistake...But now I figured it out..

If this helped you, maybe consider accepting it as the answer?
